# How can I add ExtendedCalendarView to Android gradle project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I want to convert to the new build system gradle and I have this library https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView
in eclipse I just import it as Android library.
But in idea13 and with gradle I cannot do that because it is not gradle project and I didn't find it as maven library.

How can I add this library to my project now ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the import project wizard.

Click on File-->Import Project...

and then choose the directory containing the Eclipse project of ExtendedCalendarView
and hit continue.